# Format javaFX DoubleProperty for -100.00

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx

I use a JavaFX **Text** Object and i am binding it to a **Progress Indicator**:

I want it to show how much percent(%) of work is done.

Code:

```
 text.textProperty().bind(indicator.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).asString("%.02f %%"));
```

How to make this -100.00 to be 0.00 ?I just can't figure this out...(I used an if else into multiply,divide but it does not wkorking(?"...":"...").

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
text.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(indicator.progressProperty().lessThan(0))
    .then("0.00")
    .otherwise(indicator.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).asString("%.02f %%")));
```

or

```
text.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.max(0, indicator.progressProperty()).multiply(100.00).asString("%.02f %%"));
```